# How to sum column-b values while column-a values are the same?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've simulated my problem.. because my original plan is complex to describe:

[image]

I need `C4` to be `8` because `A2 = A3 = A4`, and `5 + 2 + 1` results in `8`.

Using this logic, the expected results should be:

`C4:8    C6:10    C10:23    C12:23`

---

Well, my problem:

I can't use sumif due after the last day of the month (28, 29, 30 or 31) the next day will be 1 again.

I'm stucked on that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since oyu mention the month, do you have the month number available, or is it possible to add in third column? This would enable you to use `sumifs`

Comment: @BlindSeer. Yes, I actually have a month-column, but how would I set `C4, C6, C10, C12` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A3,"",SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1))
```

and copy down

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The first part of the **IF** insures blanks where they are needed.  The second part of the **IF** adds up all of column **B**, but removes parts of **B** that already appear in column **C**

Comment: Dude! You are awsome!

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think I understood what your formula does... but, can you explain it in more details?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 3):

If it needs to be in the same table I'd go with:

`=IF(C2<>C1,SUMIFS([Number],[Day],[@Day],[Month],[@Month]),"")`

Where column C contains the days. This way only the first row will show the sums.
Or you could use an extra table containing Year, Month and day and use:
`=SUMIFS([Number],[Day],[@Day],[Month],[@Month])`

to collect your data and have it aggregated into one table for further use.

Comment: I like this - while the other formula Gary's Student put definitely works, this one uses the fact that you have a table, and uses the Excel table named ranges (if that's what they're called...).  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following. The formula in the first cell is different than the others:

[image]

The numbers in between your target cells are still showing - is that a problem?

[image]